# y_predict has a different shape that y_test and y_train

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am working on machine learning models. However I have an issue that when I check for accuracy. I get the following.

```
'''
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [108820, 
108690]
'''
```

This is the shape of the data right before they were split.

```
 '''
 df_dep.shape
 (329757, 88)
 y_dep.shape
 (329757,)
 '''
```

Here is how they were split.

```
 '''
 # Split train, test for df_departure
 X_dep_train, X_dep_test, y_dep_train, y_dep_test = 
 train_test_split(df_dep, y_dep, test_size = .33, random_state = 42)
```

I understand that the shapes need to match, I just don't understand why I am getting a different shape.
'''
Here is the shape after the split

```
'''
X_dep_test.shape, y_dep_test.shape, X_dep_train.shape, 
y_dep_train.shape, lg_score_dep[1].shape 
((108820, 88), (108820,), (426742, 88), (426742,), (108690,))
'''
```

Here is the function that runs the ML algorithm

```
 '''
 # Logistic Regression
 def Logistic_Regression(X_train, y_train, X_test):
     from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
     c_range = [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100]
     results = {}
 for c in c_range:
     lgreg = LogisticRegression(C = c, class_weight = {0:.91, 1:.09})
     lgreg.fit(X_arr_train, y_arr_train)
     predlgreg = lgreg.predict(X_arr_test)
     results[c] = predlgreg
 return results    
 '''
```

Here is the command to run the function

```
 '''  
 # Arrival Logistic Regression
 lg_score = Logistic_Regression(X_arr_train, y_arr_train, X_arr_test)
 '''
```

Then the scoring function takes lg_score, calculates the scores and prints them. Here is that function

```
 '''
 def iterable_testing_results(test_name, y_test, array) :
     trinket = {}
     for item in array.items():
         trinket[item[0]] = accuracy_score(y_test, item[1])
     max_score = max(trinket.values())
     best_n = max(trinket, key=trinket.get)
     print(best_n)
     print(f'{best_n} makes the best value with a score of 
     {max_score}.')
     print(f'Classification report for {test_name} \n 
     {classification_report(y_arr_test, array[best_n])}.')
     print(f'Confusion Matrix for {test_name} is \n 
     {confusion_matrix(y_arr_test, array[best_n])}.')
```

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: How were these matrices produced? You did not include those details which are the ones that actually matter.

Comment: You know the dataset, you tell us? Seems like you made an error in the code that partitions `y` into train+test. Also, you have to actually post the code, not just print statements. You need to show us the actual code that generates `lg_score_dep` and what is `lg_score_dep[1]` supposed to mean; we can't know.

Comment: I just added the information you asked for

Comment: Please add a language tag!